# django using GenericForeignkey

Tags: django-models

i am getting an attribute error from my code. i don't know whats wrong. I code in VS code.the import text is becomming kinda light darken colour.

I have two apps in django store and tag. I am using generik foreign key to create a relationship between my  tag and product in my store app

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey



# Create your models here.
class Tag(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=225)

class TaggedField(models.Model):
    #what tag is applied to what object
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #Type(product,viedo, article)
    #ID
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = models.GenericForeignKey()
```

this is the error I am getting

```py
(storefront2) PS C:\Users\kesar\OneDrive\Desktop\storefront2> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kesar\.virtualenvs\storefront2-hockpoA9\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kesar\.virtualenvs\storefront2-hockpoA9\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\kesar\.virtualenvs\storefront2-hockpoA9\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\kesar\.virtualenvs\storefront2-hockpoA9\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\kesar\.virtualenvs\storefront2-hockpoA9\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kesar\.virtualenvs\storefront2-hockpoA9\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\kesar\.virtualenvs\storefront2-hockpoA9\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\kesar\.virtualenvs\storefront2-hockpoA9\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\kesar\OneDrive\Desktop\storefront2\tags\models.py", line 11, in <module>
    class TaggedField(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\kesar\OneDrive\Desktop\storefront2\tags\models.py", line 18, in TaggedField
    content_object = models.GenericForeignKey()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'GenericForeignKey'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**`GenericForeignKey`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) is a field that is defined in the `contenttypes` framework, likely because it depends on the models of a `ContenType`, etc.

You thus work with the *imported* `GenericForeignKey`, not try to obtain it as item in the `django.db.models` module:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey


class TaggedField(models.Model):
    # what tag is applied to what object
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Type(product,viedo, article)
    # ID
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # not models.GenericForeignKey
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Beware that a `GenericForeignKey` has some caveats: it can no longer guarantee *referential integrity* at the database side, and also makes querying where we look through `GenericForeignKey`s a lot harder.